Ubuntu error: Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified. Cant open display. Failed initializing GUI, exiting for XMgrace
I am on windows 11 and am trying to utilize gromacs and xmgrace in Ubuntu. I have not encountered any errors with gromacs except when trying to visualize data generated by gromacs in XMgrace. When I try to use xmgrace using the command:xmgrace filename.xvg the following error pops up:Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified. Cant open display. Failed initializing GUI, exiting. Any help would be appreciated!!
